# how to avoid that error for object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim score As Integer

    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values." Then
        score = score + 1
        Session("correct") = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values."
        Session("question") = "1.A rule of thumb for choosing indexes for a relational database includes which of the following?"
        Session("yourans") = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values."
        Session("score1") = 1
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Indexes are more useful on smaller tables." Then
        score = score + 0
        Session("correct") = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values."
        Session("question") = "1.A rule of thumb for choosing indexes for a relational database includes which of the following?"
        Session("yourans") = "Indexes are more useful on smaller tables."
        Session("score1") = 0
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Indexes are more useful for columns that do not appear frequently in the WHERE clause in queries." Then
        score = score + 0
        Session("correct") = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values."
        Session("question") = "1.A rule of thumb for choosing indexes for a relational database includes which of the following?"
        Session("yourans") = "Indexes are more useful for columns that do not appear frequently in the WHERE clause in queries."
        Session("score1") = 0
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Do not specify a unique index for the primary key of each table." Then
        score = score + 0
        Session("correct") = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values."
        Session("question") = "1.A rule of thumb for choosing indexes for a relational database includes which of the following?"
        Session("yourans") = "Do not specify a unique index for the primary key of each table."
        Session("score1") = 0
    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "" Then
        score = score + 0
        Session("correct") = "Be careful indexing attributes that have null values."
        Session("question") = "1.A rule of thumb for choosing indexes for a relational database includes which of the following?"
        Session("yourans") = "No Answer"
        Session("score1") = 0
    End If


    Session("per") = Math.Round(score / 1 * 100)
    If Session("per") <= 50 Then
        Session("state") = "Poor Your Aptitude skills need to be improved!"
    ElseIf Session("per") <= 60 Then
        Session("state") = "Poor spend more time!"
    ElseIf Session("per") <= 70 Then
        Session("state") = "Not bad You need to pratice!"
    ElseIf Session("per") <= 80 Then
        Session("state") = "good with a little more work You could be really proud!"
    ElseIf Session("per") <= 90 Then
        Session("state") = "Very good you still missed one or more question pratice!"
    ElseIf Session("per") <= 99 Then
        Session("state") = " Excellent Which question(s) did You Miss!"
    ElseIf Session("per") <= 100 Then
        Session("state") = "Perfect You Should be really Product!"
    End If
    Session("a13") = "You score is " & score _
   & " Out of 10," & Session("per") & "%," & Session("state")
    Session("f") = score
    con.Open()
    qur = "insert into res values('" + Session("rn").ToString() + "','" + Session("na").ToString() + "','" + Session("cl").ToString() + "','" + Session("de").ToString() + "','" + Session("da").ToString() + "','" + Session("mn").ToString() + "','" + Session("em").ToString() + "','" + Session("f").ToString() + "','" + Session("per").ToString() + "','" + Session("state").ToString() + "')"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(qur, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Close()
    Response.Redirect("Aptituderesult.aspx")
End Sub
```

resulting page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Label1.Text = Session("us11").ToString()
    Label2.Text = Session("question").ToString()
    Label3.Text = Session("correct").ToString()
    Label4.Text = Session("yourans").ToString()
    Label5.Text = Session("score1").ToString()
    Label6.Text = Session("a13").ToString()
End Sub
```

can any one help me out

Comment: can you share the error log? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: am developed online aptitude test projects.resulting pages display error on object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: you still not clear at which place and after which event you getting this error?

Comment: lable2.text=session("question").tostring() here getting on object reference not set to an instance of an object this error

Comment: seems null value assigning to label2.text
can you try below code
lable2.text=Convert.ToString(session("question"))

Comment: again that error are occur sir

Comment: how to solve that error

Comment: lable2.text=Convert.ToString(session("question")) again display the error for object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

When this type of error arises, then it is clear that you have either not initialized the value of the control etc and are trying to use the same.
In this case the value cannot be retriedved from the session as session might be null, there is no value in the same.
The better way is to check for example:

```
if(Session["us11"]!=null)
{
..//the assign the value
}
```

Comment: Nothing to display resulting page

Comment: am open a new from and develop the result page it work that page.thank u